# How to define common property(ies) for all entities in entity framework

Tags: inheritance, entity-framework-4, mapping

Imagine that I have UserId (actually we do have roughly four columns like userId, adddate, moddate etc. for almost all tables) column for almost all of the entities.

How can I make such a column(s) to be available in a separate entity (say parent entity) and make all other entities (child entities) inheriting from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using generated entity classes (either POCO or `EntityObject`) you will have to define base abstract entity in your model (EDMX) and derive other entities in TPC inheritance - simply don't do that because it will introduce so many other problems - for example you will access all entities from the single `ObjectSet` of the base type, PK will have to be unique among all your entities, etc.

Another way is either using custom POCO classes (not generated) or custom T4 template to create common object inheritance but still using normal entities in the designer without inheritance. I thought that this is not possible but few days ago I tested it with simple example and it worked - but I'm still little bit suspicious to this approach.

Comment: I wonder how such an important thing like shared functionality among all entities (i.e: CreatedDate, UpdatedDate, etc...), needs so many workarounds, with increased possibilities of messing things up. Although in my experience this is easy to implement in CodeFirst!

Answer (score 2):

Try using T4 templates like it is described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsimmons/archive/2008/10/27/using-t4-templates-to-generate-ef-classes.aspx) or [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2009/12/05/t4-templates-in-entity-framework-4.aspx), [modify the template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg558520) to contain a base class (inherited from EntityObject) having these properties, and inherit each class from this base class.